# Numpy : How to concatenate array of objects keep the dtype consistent

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to stack multiple arrays in a single array and keep the data type float for all

using this statement

```
transition = np.hstack((s, [np.vstack(a).astype(np.float), r, d], s_))
```

present output like this

```
[1502.0 1469.0 1563.0 1610.0 1637.0 1625.0 1580.0 1453.0 1264.0 1201.0
 1352.0 1526.0 1738.0 1788.0 1786.0 1709.0 1669.0 1621.0 1618.0 1651.0
 1655.0 1672.0 1671.0 1683.0 1555.2589513700764
 array([[256.],
       [ 69.],
       [484.]]) 6329 True 1469.0 1563.0
 1610.0 1637.0 1625.0 1580.0 1453.0 1264.0 1201.0 1352.0 1526.0 1738.0
 1788.0 1786.0 1709.0 1669.0 1621.0 1618.0 1651.0 1655.0 1672.0 1671.0
 1683.0 1555.2589513700764 1541.0463344821703]
```

i want to remove the array part and make it smooth as

```
[1502.0 1469.0 1563.0 1610.0 1637.0 1625.0 1580.0 1453.0 1264.0 1201.0
 1352.0 1526.0 1738.0 1788.0 1786.0 1709.0 1669.0 1621.0 1618.0 1651.0
 1655.0 1672.0 1671.0 1683.0 1555.2589513700764
 256. 69. 484. 6329 True 1469.0 1563.0 1610.0 1637.0 1625.0 1580.0 1453.0 1264.0 1201.0 1352.0 1526.0 1738.0 1788.0 1786.0 1709.0 1669.0 1621.0 1618.0 1651.0 1655.0 1672.0 1671.0 1683.0 1555.2589513700764 1541.0463344821703]
```

Comment: It looks to me like one or more of your arrays is `dtype=object` (the presence of the `True` and the mix of float precision).  And result is also `object`.  If you want a float result, all input arrays have to be float and/or integer.

Comment: so change every sub-array to float right?

Comment: Why are you using `vstack`, if you're aiming for a horizontal result?

Comment: Can you show `s.shape`, `a.shape`, `r.shape`, `d.shape`, and `s_.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want

```
np.concatenate((s, a, [r, d], s_))
```

Comment: shape is not as expected also True is missing
`could not broadcast input array from shape (55) into shape (53)`